# Get value of a group based on value of many columns by priority

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Pyspark dataframe that is like this:

| ID | Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Type4 | Type5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 |  | 100 |  |  |  |
| 001 |  |  |  |  | 200 |
| 001 |  |  | 300 |  |  |
| 001 |  |  |  | 150 |  |
| 002 | 0 |  |  |  |  |
| 002 |  |  | 300 |  |  |
| 002 |  | 200 |  |  |  |
| 002 |  |  |  |  | 400 |

For each row there is a Type column that is filled. I would like to make only one Type column for each ID, and that Type column will be like: if Type1 is not null and Type1 > 0 then take Type1 else if Type2 is not null and Type2 > 0 then take Type2 and so on. Priority Type1 > Type2 > Type3 > Type4 > Type5

The final dataframe is supposed to be like this:

| ID | Type |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 100 |
| 002 | 200 |

how can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi it would be nice to have pyspark solution since we have limited capacity and we run with this Spark session.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start by creating your dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        ("001", None, 100, None, None, None),
        ("001", None, None, None, None, 200),
        ("001", None, None, 300, None, None),
        ("001", None, None, None, 150, None),
        ("002", 0, None, None, None, None),
        ("002", None, None, 300, None, None),
        ("002", None, 200, None, None, None),
        ("002", None, None, None, None, 400),
    ],
    ["ID", "Type1", "Type2", "Type3", "Type4", "Type5"],
)
```

You can get your wanted behaviour by using the following functions:

- `df.groupBy` to only get 1 row per `ID` column
- `pyspark.sql.functions.first` with the `ignoreNulls` argument on `True` to grab the first non null value per column to aggregate after `df.groupBy`
- `pyspark.sql.functions.when` to put all values that are <= 0 to `null`
- `pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce` to only keep the first non-null value in a list of columns (we'll use the order that you specified together with for comprehension to stay dynamic)

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

my_range = range(1, 6)
output = (
    df.groupBy("ID")
    .agg(*[F.first(f"Type{i}", ignorenulls=True).alias(f"Type{i}") for i in my_range])
    .select(
        "ID",
        F.coalesce(
            *[
                F.when(F.col(f"Type{i}") <= 0, F.lit(None))
                .otherwise(F.col(f"Type{i}"))
                for i in my_range
            ],
        ).alias("Type"),
    )
)

>>> output.show()
+---+----+
| ID|Type|
+---+----+
|001| 100|
|002| 200|
+---+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use coalesce for such use case, this is how:

> suppose df is your spark dataframe

```
df_result = df.withColumn(
    "Type",
    coalesce(
        col("Type1"),
        col("Type2"),
        col("Type3"),
        col("Type4"),
        col("Type5"),
    )
).filter(col("Type") > 0)

# Select the final columns
result = df_result.select("ID", "Type")
```

coalesce will pick the first non null positive value from the given columns in order of their priority. On top of it we have filter to keep only the values that are greater than 0.

Let me know if this works for you, do share your feedback and keep coding.